# Is $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ profinite?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, profinite-groups

Serre's Galois Cohomology states that $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is a profinite group. How can one see this? Is there a way to identify the open normal subgroups of finite index of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ (when we see it with the product topology, for example)?

EDIT: I am considering the definition:

$$SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) = \left\{M \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z}_p) | \det(M) = 1\right\}$$

and the topology induced by the product topology in $\prod_{n^2} \mathbb{Z}_p$. We know it's a topological group but it's not obvious to us why we have the characterization
$$SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p) = \varprojlim SL_n(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})$$
which would surely make it the limit of finite discrete groups, and thus, profinite.

Comment: It's the inverse limit of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)$, which are finite. So yes, it is profinite.

Comment: (I suppose you need to show the topology from the limit is the same as some other topology on the special linear group.)

Comment: The proj lim characterization shows that there's a unique map from some other topologized $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ to the proj lim, and must be injective. Then one can apply the general idea that a continuous injection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is open, hence is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews we suspected so, but that's not clear to us. See our edit.